# How can I delete customers that never logged in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

How can I delete customers who never logged in? I can't find any solution. 
I think I have over 40000 customers who never logged in, so I can't delete them by hand.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set the option **System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Log > Enable Log** to **YES** then you can check `log_customer`
table and get `customer_id` who logged into system before. After that you can write a script to delete customer whose id is not matching with these ID.

Answer (score 0):

Add script in your root folder and run it.

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$collection = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();

foreach ($collection as $customer){
    $log = Mage::getModel('log/visitor_online')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())->getFirstItem();
    if(!$log->getId()){ 
        echo 'Customer with email '.$customer->getEmail().' is deleted </br>';
        $customer->delete();

    }
}

?>
```